# How to compare a string

Tags: c, string

How to compare a string coming from serial monitor with some predefined text stored  as a local variable?
If I say:

```
int led = 2;
String a = " abcds";

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  String b = Serial.read();
  Serial.println(b);

  if (b != a) {
    digitalWrite(2,LOW);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
  }
}
```

just as an example, this code will not compile because on the serial I receive bytes and I want to compare with a string. 
So my question is...
how should be done?

Comment: For which arduino board? Most of us try to avoid the String class for the arduino uno. As soon as a character is available, you add it to a buffer or to a String. Sometimes the data from the serial port is closed with a linefeed, then you can process the text in the buffer or in the String when a linefeed is read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

version using String (not recommended, but it makes simpler to understand the following C-string version)

```
#define LED 2
const char* a = "abcd";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    String s = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    s.trim();
    if (s == a) {
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

the version with C-string:

```
#define LED 2
const char* a = "abcd";
char buffer[32];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    size_t l = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', buffer, sizeof(buffer - 1));
    if (buffer[l - 1] == '\r') {
      l--;
    }
    buffer[l] = 0; // the terminating zero
    Serial.println(buffer);
    if (strcmp(buffer, a) == 0) {
      digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As I already commented on VE7JRO's post, `Stream::readBytesUntil()` will wait for the terminating character until it gets it or it times out, which can lead to long delays during which the sketch is unresponsive. A better solution is to read only whatever is available, and process the buffer when an LF is read. C.f. the blog post [Reading Serial on the Arduino](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino), by Majenko, for a better solution.

Comment: The `String` version works perfectly, but I can't get the `C-string` version to work. For me, the serial monitor shows "abcd" written out to 2 lines: line 1 prints "ab", line 2 prints "cd". Perhaps it's the old version of the IDE I'm using (1.0.6.2). I like that you provided 2 example sketches so the OP can see the difference in compile size: `String` 4364 bytes VS `C-string` 2746 bytes.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, it will wait only if terminating character is not present. the timeout can be set to for example to 10 milliseconds with setTimeout. in many cases it is better to wait for the stream as continue with other things in loop and then return to read an overflowed buffer

Comment: If your `loop()` takes so long that the serial buffer overflows, then you have probably done something very wrong. You can only afford to wait for the whole message to be received if you have no time-sensitive code outside of interrupt context. `Stream::readBytesUntil()` and `delay()` work in the same team: they can help you write simpler code if you can afford keeping the CPU busy doing nothing, but their use is not a good programming habit in general.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, if the gaps between the received bytes are microseconds small, but available() would sometimes return 0, what is a good way to read a command from Stream? the sketch has nothing to do, until this command is received. Other case:  with networking done in external modules and with Arduino libraries you can't have a 'real-time' loop. it could take some seconds until a web server sends a response, but then the bytes go in fast and always more than the serial buffer size.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a Google search on "Arduino String" you should find a class reference on the String class. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/

It has a function `compareTo()` that should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

C has strcmp() function that is used to compare two strings. It will return zero if two strings are equal non zero when not.

Comment: I started to suggest the same thing, and then noticed that the OP is using Arduino String objects, not C strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the loop() code from the SafeString_ReadCmdsTimed.ino example in the SafeString library available from the Arduino library manager.  It is non-blocking, i.e. no delays.

There is an extensive [tutorial and examples available for SafeStrings](https://www.forward.com.au/pfod/ArduinoProgramming/SafeString/index.html).
SafeStrings has built-in error checking and debugging.  SafeStrings provides the functionality of Strings without the memory fragmentation problems of dynamic memory allocation.

If you are reading from telnet there is also a processbackspaces() method in SafeStrings to handle terminal typing corrections.
The delimiters are whatever you would like.  The example handles Windows, Unix and Mac end-of-lines.

```
char delimiters[] = " .,\r\n"; // space dot comma CR NL are cmd delimiters

void loop() {
  if (input.read(Serial)) {  // read from Serial, returns true if at least one character was added to SafeString input
    input.debug("after read => ");
    timeout.start(TIMEOUT_MS); // restart a 0.1sec timer every time something is read
  }

  if (input.nextToken(token, delimiters)) { // process at most one token per loop does not return tokens longer than input.capacity()
    token.debug("after nextToken => ");

    if (token == startCmdStr) {
      running = true;  Serial.print(F("start at ")); Serial.println(loopCounter);

    } else if (token == stopCmdStr) {
      running = false; Serial.print(F("stop at ")); Serial.println(loopCounter);

    } else if (token == resetCmdStr) {
      loopCounter = 0; Serial.print(F("reset Counter:")); Serial.println(loopCounter);

    }// else  // not a valid cmd ignore
  }
  if (timeout.justFinished()) { // nothing received for 0.1secs, terminated last chars so token will be processed.
    input += delimiters[0]; // any delimiter will do
    SafeString::Output.print(F("Input timed out"));
  }
  // rest of code here is executed while the user typing in commands
  if (running) {
    loopCounter++;
    if ((loopCounter % 100000) == 0) {
      Serial.print(F("Counter:")); Serial.println(loopCounter);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation, you appear to be the author of the site you've linked multiple times.

Comment: Sure will add a 'my' to future posts.  There are a number of other free libraries/tutorials on my site, but that specific link is to the detailed tutorial for SafeString.which I am putting forward as a 'safe' replacement for Arduino Strings.  Check out the tutorial for all the reasons you should be using SafeString instead of Arduino Strings